# How to solve type mismatch when compiler finds Serializable instead of the match type?

Tags: scala, parsing, rdd, type-mismatch, scalaz7

I have have the following parser to parse arithmetic expressions containing Float and RDD :

```
 import scalaz._
 import Scalaz._

 def term2: Parser[List[\/[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]]] = rep(factor2)
 def factor2: Parser[\/[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = pathxml | num
 def pathxml: Parser[ RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]] = pathIdent ^^ { s => pathToRDD(s)} //pathToRDD is a function that gets the path in string and create an RDD from the file inside that path and pathIdent parse to see whether the input string is a path or not
 def num: Parser[\/[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (n => n.left[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]].toFloat)
```

Getting the following error:

```
  [error]  type mismatch;   
  [error]  found   : ParseExp.this.Parser[Serializable]
  [error]  required: ParseExp.this.Parser[scalaz.\/[Float,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]]]
  [error]   def factor2: Parser[\/[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = pathxml | num
  [error]                                                                     ^
```

I am new in Scala and don/t know how I can solve this error

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Serializable` (or similarly `Product`, or both together) is almost always an indication that you're trying to treat two types as the same when they're not. For example:

```
scala> if (true) "a" else List(1)
res0: java.io.Serializable = a
```

The type of a conditional expression is the *least upper bound* of the types of its two branches—i.e. the most specific type the branches have in common. Here we have a `String` and a `List[Int]`, which are both instances of `AnyRef`, but otherwise don't have anything in common besides being `Serializable`. The fact that they're both `Serializable` is more specific than the fact that they're both subtypes of `AnyRef`, so that's the inferred type.

The type of a sequence is inferred similarly:

```
scala> List("a", "b", "c", 'd)
res1: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(a, b, c, 'd)
```

In general any time you see `Serializable`, you should start hunting for something whose type isn't the same as its neighbors or siblings.

In your case `pathxml | num` is going to be the least upper bound of `Parser[RDDThing]` and `Parser[Float \/ RDDThing]`, which is again `Parser[Serializable]`. You should be able to fix this by lifting `pathxml` into the larger type in your `factor2` definition with `pathxml.map(_.right) | num`.

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation. I did the suggestion and changed the code, I am getting the following error now: type mismatch found"Product with Serializable" why is that?!

Comment: @Rubbic What happens if you try adding a new (possibly temporary) `val` for `pathxml.map(_.right)`? Can you type that as `Parser[Float \/ RDDThing]`? You might need to use something like `pathxml.map(_.right[Float])`.

Comment: if I add "[Float]" it will give me the following error :
method right of type scala.util.Either.RightProjection[Float,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]] does not take type parameters.